# Writing back to iterator while looping over more than one collection

Tags: c++, boost, collections, iterator, boost-foreach

I would like to loop through two collections using iterators, modifying one based on a (sufficiently complex) algorithm involving the other. Consider the following minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/range/combine.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp> // tie
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main(void) {
  // input data; never mind how these get filled
  int aa[] = {2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21};
  int bb[] = {1, 0, 1, 1,  0,  1};
  vector<int> a (&aa[0], &aa[sizeof(aa)/sizeof(aa[0])]);
  vector<int> b (&bb[0], &bb[sizeof(bb)/sizeof(bb[0])]);

  // output storage; assume it has always correct dim.
  vector<int> c (a.size());

  // iterate through two coll., reading from both
  int p, q;
  BOOST_FOREACH (tie(p,q), combine(a,b)) { // loop1
    cout << p << "*" << q << "=" << p*q << endl;
  }

  // iterate through one coll., writing to it
  BOOST_FOREACH (int& r, c) { // loop2
    r = 42;
  }

  // iterate through two coll., reading from one, writing to the other?
  BOOST_FOREACH (??? p, s ???, combine(a,c)) { // loop3
    s = p * 2;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

How do I declare the part between the `???`s (or otherwise change the parameters in loop3)?

Comment: Your question could use some serious cleanup -- in particular, you've done so little to explain what you're really trying to accomplish with your third loop that it's next to impossible to really give a solid answer as it stands right now -- I've given an answer, but WRT your third loop, it's impossible to give more than a rather wild guess about what you really want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value type of a `zip_range` is a tuple of references to elements:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <boost/range/combine.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

int main(int ac,char* av[])
{
  // input data; never mind how these get filled
  int aa[] = {2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21};
  int bb[] = {1, 0, 1, 1,  0,  1};
  std::vector<int> a(boost::begin(aa), boost::end(aa));
  std::vector<int> const b(boost::begin(bb), boost::end(bb));

  // output storage; assume it has always correct dim.
  std::vector<int> c (a.size());

  typedef boost::tuple<int const&, int&> val_t;
  BOOST_FOREACH(val_t const& v, boost::combine(a, c)) {
    v.get<1>() = v.get<0>() * 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: So, the clue is that since one cannot initialize a pair of references, one gets the pair, and then use the reference it returns! (For future readers of this question: one can also declare `int& s = v.get<1>();`)

Comment: This strikes me as "here's a hammer big enough to force your round peg into a square hole".

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you're overusing `BOOST_FOREACH` to an almost shocking degree. Like `std::foreach`, this should be one of your *last* choices of algorithm.

Your third loop should almost certainly be written using `std::transform`. It's intended to take an input range, transform it, and deposit the result in an output range (or take two input ranges, combine them, and put the result in a third, such as in your first (mis)use of BOOST_FOREACH).

Using this, your third loop comes out something like:

```
// c[i] = a[i] * 2, i = 0..N-1
std::transform(begin(a), end(a), begin(c), [](int i) { return i * 2; });
```

As for your second, it looks like you really want `std::fill_n`.

```
std::fill_n(begin(c), end(c), 42);
```

Now, it's certainly true that something based on ranges (e.g., the algorithms in [Boost Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range/doc/html/index.html)) could make this a bit simpler by replacing each `begin(X), end(X)` pair with a single parameter. Nonetheless, these are already clearly superior to the BOOST_FOREACH versions with miscellaneous `tie`s and `combine`s to try force your square pegs into round holes.

Comment: You are easily shocked... ;-) If the algorithm needs surrounding context, it may be more readable to use a simple loop than to refactor everything into an object holding the context -- I think that is case-dependant. The examples here are only to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @RolKau: while there are cases where a loop can be a reasonable alternative as well, they're honestly pretty unusual -- and you have *not* shown such a case here.